# keyPressed() function not responding (Processing 3.0)

Tags: processing

I was trying to recreate tic tac toe to pick up Processing again. I remember that before I put functions into keyPressed() ifs, the program ran fine, inputting lines of text into the console everytime the user typed a number into the console. Now every time I press keys, nothing shows up, not even the error message that I assigned just in case the user decides to type anything in besides numbers. Now I'm not sure where I went wrong. Since I'm not exactly a pro at writing Processing, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Code:

```java
String pos = "";
boolean isx = true;
boolean onepressed = false;
boolean twopressed = false;
boolean threepressed = false;
boolean fourpressed = false;
boolean fivepressed = false;
boolean sixpressed = false;
boolean sevenpressed = false;
boolean eightpressed = false;
boolean ninepressed = false;
void setup() {
  size(1000,1000);
  frameRate(60);
  background(255,255,255);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
}
void keyPressedUpdate() {
  if (isx == true) {
    print("An x has been placed in the ");
    print(pos);
    print(" of the board");
    print("Currently x's turn");
    isx = false;
  } else if (isx == false) {
    print("An o has been placed in the ");
    print(pos);
    print(" of the board");
    print("Currently o's turn");
    isx = true;
  }
}
void keyPressed() {
  if (key == '1' && onepressed == false) {
    pos = "top-left corner";
    keyPressedUpdate();
    onepressed = true;
  } else if (key == '2' && twopressed == false) {
    pos = "top-center square";
    keyPressedUpdate();
    twopressed = true;
  } else if (key == '3' && threepressed == false) {
    pos = "top-right corner";
    keyPressedUpdate();
    threepressed = true;
  } else if (key == '4' && fourpressed == false) {
    pos = "center-left square";
    keyPressedUpdate();
    fourpressed = true;
  } else if (key == '5' && fivepressed == false) {
    pos = "center square";
    keyPressedUpdate();
    fivepressed = true;
  } else if (key == '6' && sixpressed == false) {
    pos = "center-right square";
    keyPressedUpdate();
    sixpressed = true;
  } else if (key == '7' && sevenpressed == false) {
    pos = "bottom-left corner";
    keyPressedUpdate();
    sevenpressed = true;
  } else if (key == '8' && eightpressed == false) {
    pos = "center-bottom square";
    keyPressedUpdate();
    eightpressed = true;
  } else if (key == '9' && ninepressed == false) {
    pos = "bottom-right corner";
    keyPressedUpdate();
    ninepressed = true;
  } else {
    print("Please enter a number, not a letter or symbol.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using event functions like `keyPressed()`, you need to have a `draw()` function, even if you don't actually draw anything in it.

In other words, add a `draw()` function:

```
void draw(){}
```

Now you'll see your print statements in the console.